# How do I configure CMake to build with newly installed GCC compiler?

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake

I want to have CMake build using a gcc compiler I installed on my MacOSx

I built the gcc-5.4.0 distribution and installed it at /usr/local/gcc-5.4.0
all the compilers are under /usr/local/gcc-5.4.0/bin

I am using the CMake version 3.6.1

Comment: It's very easy if you configure your project through cmake-gui, starting from a clean build directory. Among the options you have available at the beginning, there's the possibility to choose the exact path to the compilers.

Answer (score 2):

[Everything is detailed in the CMake FAQ](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F)

> How do I use a different compiler? Method 1: use environment variables
>
> For C and C++, set the CC and CXX environment variables. This method
>   is not guaranteed to work for all generators. (Specifically, if you
>   are trying to set Xcode's GCC_VERSION, this method confuses Xcode.)
>
> For example:
>
> CC=gcc-4.2 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.2 cmake -G "Your Generator"
>   path/to/your/source
>
> Method 2: use cmake -D
>
> Set the appropriate CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER variable(s) to a valid compiler
>   name or full path on the command-line using cmake -D.
>
> For example:
>
> cmake -G "Your Generator" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-4.2 -D
>   CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.2 path/to/your/source
>
> Method 3 (avoid): use set()
>
> Set the appropriate CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER variable(s) to a valid compiler
>   name or full path in a list file using set(). This must be done before
>   any language is set (ie before any project() or enable_language()
>   command).
>
> For example:
>
> set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc-4.2") set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
>   "/usr/bin/g++-4.2")
>
> project("YourProjectName")